Use two different layouts in Laravel inertia.js and vue 3
I'm using laravel 10 for some projects. I need to keep two different layouts and I separating from app.js and customer.js and keep one blade file.
This is app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- <link id="theme-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css"> -->
    <link id="theme-css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/tailwind-light/theme.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <?php
$route = Route::current();
$user = Auth::user();
     ?>
    @routes
    @if (($user && !$user->hasRole('user') && !$user->hasRole('restricted_user')) || $route->uri == 'login')
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
    @else
        @vite(['resources/js/customer.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
    @endif
    @inertiaHead
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    @inertia
</body>

</html>

this is customer.js (js/customer.js)
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});

this is app.js (js/app.js)
import './bootstrap';
// import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';
import LaravelPermissionToVueJS from './permissions/laravel-permission-to-vuejs';

/*
there are more imports here
*/

import '@/assets/styles.scss';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(ToastService)
            .use(DialogService)
            .use(ConfirmationService)

            /*
            .component()...
            */
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});


I use one layout for admin and other for customer.
Problem is when I switch the layouts it keeps the pervious layout styles (broken styles) until it manually refreshes. How can I clear the previous styles and load current layout styles without manual refresh?
Thank you.

Inertia doesn't reload the whole page so the blade template is not recreated when you just change from user to customer and back. You could however have different layouts defined in vue and load there the necessary packages for your application.

This is how I do it:
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const Layout1= defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('@/path/to/Layout1.vue')
)

createInertiaApp({
  progress: {
    color:'#e40613'
  },

  title: title => {
    if (title != "")
    {
      return `APP - ${title}`;
    }
    else
    {
      return `APP`;
    }
  },
  
  resolve: async(name) => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob("./**/*.vue");

    let page = await pages[`./${name}.vue`]();
    if (name.startsWith('Xyz/')) //Xyz should be a regex/string match, so you can filter pages for layout 1
    {
      page.default.layout = Layout1;
    }
    else
    {
      page.default.layout = DefaultLayout;
    }
    return page;
  },
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .component('Head', Head)
      .mount(el)
  },
})

As @parapente noted, Inertia utilizises only one blade entry point, everything else inside is Inertia doing its thing as an SPA.
Mind you, those layouts and pages are nested in resources/js/Pages/Xyz/Home.vue and layouts in resources/js/Layouts/Layout1.vue
Hope this helps.
Best regards,
Mega Aleksandar
